# Favicon not showing up on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, favicon

The favicon was working when I first installed the theme and now it has stopped working.

http://veloxity.us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to close the script tag on line 13

```
<!--Header Styling-->
<script type="text/javascript">var isloaded = false;
```

Should be

```
<!--Header Styling-->
<script type="text/javascript">var isloaded = false;</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! This was the issue =)

Answer (score 0):

`shortcut-icon` is a bit old school and I'm not sure if that supports anything other than the `ico` format.

Try

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/favicon.gif" />
```

Do you have a favicon.ico in the site root?